# background image loads slow whereas the image in the site open fast

Tags: html, css, fonts, background-image

I have a site radhanath-swami.info. I am using a background image . the following is the code in the head

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    BODY {
        background-image: url("http://www.radhanath-swami.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pattern36.jpeg") !important;
    } 
</STYLE>
```

the pattern36.jpeg image is of size 23.6 kb

Also in the front page i have many images which are 90kb sizes.

But the background image shows not before the loading of the other images.

Also the font loads very slow. first the title is shown in normal font then after the google font is downloaded it shows the google font

Comment: It loads fine for me. May be you should reduce its dimensions if its just a pattern and set a `background-color` similar to your pattern color so that users wouldn't notice?

Comment: i am having a slow internet connection. is it because of that

Answer (score 2):

You have to take into account that the background image is from a separate server. If the other images are stored on your ftp or if your connection to their urls are better, they will load faster.

In short: This might not be an error on your side.

If all of your images comes from external sources, you can test the speed of the individual images by pasting the url [here](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/).